# Change the Background of Select/Click listview Item - Android

Tags: android, listview, background

I am working on the `quiz application`.For that I am using `listview for the dispaly the answers options`, I want to change the listview background color when user select the listview item, If answer is `correct` then set the `green background` and `wrong` then set `red background`

I am tring so much, but i don,t get the solution.

Adapter class

```
public class ListviewAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

public List<String> Questions;  

public Activity context;  
public LayoutInflater inflater;
private int[] colors = new int[] { 0x30505050, 0x30808080 };

private String[] opt_no;
public static View change_color;

public ListviewAdapter(Activity context,List<String> answers, String[] que_opt_no) {  
    super();  

    this.context = context;  
    this.Questions = answers; 
    this.opt_no = que_opt_no;

    //this.inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);  
}  

@Override  
public int getCount() {  
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
    return Questions.size();  
}  

@Override  
public Object getItem(int position) {  
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
     return Questions.get(position);  
}  

@Override  
public long getItemId(int position) {  
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
    return 0;  
}  

public static class ViewHolder  
{  

    TextView txtquestion;  
    TextView txtquestion_no;  
}  

@Override  
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {  
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub  

    ViewHolder holder; 

    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
   // this.inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    String fontPath = "fonts/Face Your Fears.ttf";

    if(convertView==null)  
    {  
        holder = new ViewHolder();  
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.quiz_questions_listitem, null);  

        holder.txtquestion = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView_option);
        holder.txtquestion_no = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView_option_no);

       // holder.txtquestion .setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(convertView.getContext().getAssets(),fontPath));

        convertView.setTag(holder);  

    }  
    else  
        holder=(ViewHolder)convertView.getTag(); 


   /* int colorPos = position % colors.length;
    convertView.setBackgroundColor(colors[colorPos]); */

    change_color = convertView;

   // convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.listview_background);


    holder.txtquestion.setText(Questions.get(position)); 
    holder.txtquestion_no.setText(opt_no[position]); 

    return convertView;  
}  

/*public static void setbackground(){

    String answer = SelectedAnswer.getAnswer();
       if (Display_questions.currentQ.getAnswer().trim().equals(answer.trim()))
    { 

          Toast.makeText(change_color.getContext(), "red",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         change_color.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.listview_background);
        //ListviewAdapter.change_color.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.listview_background);
        //Display_questions.currentGame.incrementRightAnswers();
    }
    else{

        Toast.makeText(change_color.getContext(), "Blue",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        change_color.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.listview_false_background);
        //Display_questions.currentGame.incrementWrongAnswers();
    }
}*/

}
```

Java class

```
 public class Display_questions extends Activity{

 public static Question currentQ;
  public static GamePlay currentGame;
 ListView listview;

ListviewAdapter adapter;

String que_opt_no[] = {"a) ","b)","c) ","d) "};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.quiz_questions);

             listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.questions_list);
        listview.setItemsCanFocus(false);

        GoToNextQuestion();
}

private void GoToNextQuestion() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> myAdapter, View myView, int pos, long mylng) {


                String  selectedFromList = (String) listview.getItemAtPosition(pos);

                 SelectedAnswer.setAnswer(selectedFromList);

                 if (!checkAnswer(pos)) return;

                if (currentGame.isGameOver()){

                    Intent i = new Intent(Display_questions.this, Display_result.class);
                    i.putExtra("Timer_Value", TimerTime);
                    startActivity(i); 

                    finish();
                }
                else{

                    GoToNextQuestion();


                } 
            }
          });

     setQuestions();
  }

 private void setQuestions() {

    // set the question text from current question

    String question = currentQ.getQuestion().trim();
    TextView qText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_questions);
    qText.setText(question);


    // set the available options
    List<String> answers = currentQ.getQuestionOptions();

     adapter = new ListviewAdapter(this,answers,que_opt_no);

     listview.setAdapter(adapter);

}

 static boolean checkAnswer(int selectedPosition) {

    String answer = SelectedAnswer.getAnswer();

    if (answer==null){

        return false;
    }
    else {

         AnswerStates state = AnswerStates.NONE;

        if (currentQ.getAnswer().trim().equals(answer.trim()))
        { 

            //listview.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.listview_background);

            currentGame.incrementRightAnswers();
            state = AnswerStates.RIGHT;

        }
        else{

            //ListviewAdapter.setbackground();
            currentGame.incrementWrongAnswers();
            state = AnswerStates.WRONG;

        }

        adapter.setSelectedAnswerState(selectedPosition, state);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        return true;
    }
}

  }
```

**Edit :**
check My images :
1.)
[image]
2.)

[image]

Comment: Do You need to change listview or selected listview item background?

Comment: want change the color of the selected listview item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to go with the following way:
Adapter class:
add storing of selected position and its state (CORRECT/INCORRECT) or color, e.g.:

```
public class ListviewAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

enum AnswerStates {
    // Colors can be provided also for bg
    WRONG(R.drawable.wrong_bg),
    RIGHT(R.drawable.right_bg),
    NONE(R.drawable.list_item_bg);
    /** Drawable id to be used for answer state */
    private int mBg;

    private AnswerStates(int bg) {
        mBg = bg;
    }

    /** getter for drawabale for answer state */
    int getBg() {
        return mBg;
    }
}
...
/** Position of selected answer */
private int mSelectedPosition = -1;
/** State of selected answer */
private AnswerStates mSelectedAnswerState = AnswerStates.NONE;
...
/** Setter for selected answer */
public void setSelectedAnswerState(int selectedPosition, AnswerStates state) {
    mSelectedPosition = selectedPosition;
    mSelectedAnswerState = state;
}    

@Override  
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ...
    // Your stuff
    ...

    if (position == mSelectedPosition) {
        convertView.setBackgroundResource(mSelectedAnswerState.getBg());
    } else {
        // use default bg
        convertView.setBackgroundResource(AnswerStates.NONE.getBg());
    }

    return convertView;
}
...
}
```

And Activity class:

```
public class Display_questions extends Activity{
    ...
    // Added position parameter to the function
    static boolean checkAnswer(int selectedPosition) {
        //getSelectedAnswer();

        String answer = SelectedAnswer.getAnswer();

        if (answer==null){

            return false;
        }
        else {

            AnswerStates state = AnswerStates.NONE;

            if (currentQ.getAnswer().trim().equals(answer.trim()))
            { 
               //   here set the background Green color
               currentGame.incrementRightAnswers();
               state = AnswerStates.RIGHT;
            }
            else{
               //   here set the background red color
               //ListviewAdapter.setbackground();
               currentGame.incrementWrongAnswers();
               state = AnswerStates.WRONG;
            }

            adapter.setSelectedAnswerState(selectedPosition, state);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            return true;
        }
     }
}
```

This way is more reliable than another answer, because it will work even if list with answers get scrolled and views get reused by list view.

Comment: Thanks,I am using `int select_Item_position = listview.getSelectedItemPosition();` into `listview.setOnItemClickListener` Method, and passing parameter like ` if (!checkAnswer(select_Item_position)) return;` But every time when I select the `list-item` it gives me position `-1`. Is there `-1` write or wrong for every time?

Comment: I would suggest to use 'int pos' parameter in setOnItemClickListener  as selectedPosition for checkAnswer().

Comment: Into my app display the question(Textview) and four options(listview), when select listview item then go to next questions.I have apply your code but it works for only `last question`.I mean change the background only last question.

Comment: is there separate control like 'go to next question'? If no and You just show next question, then obviously You won't observe answers from previous question (which is not visible). Could you be more specific about which answers should stay selected? Should list keep highlighted all selected answers for all questions?

Comment: hi, Thanks for answer, But i didn't understand your que.
If you have look in image 1 which i had uploaded then u will find the fully function with color. i.e. when i choose Answer then it will  change the color. But this will happend in only last que. Example right now i had put 5 que. so effect will so in only 5th que. & ans. It is not showing effect in 1st to 4 th que. I had check all the coding but still didn't understand. please check the images and coding as well. Please let me know.

Comment: I mean, there's no delay between questions in Your code, so it's obvious that You're not seeing changes in colors until last question (because every next question cleans previous selection due to new adapter). Probably You need to introduce some delay between questions, but it's not related to 'Change the Background' question. Try to introduce some delay before calling GoToNextQuestion() e.g. via Handler.postDelayed();

Comment: Thanks a lot once again. Good job.it,s working perfect as I want.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to change the background of listview or the selected item when a correct answer is selected.

```
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> myAdapter, View myView, int pos, long mylng) {


             String  selectedFromList = (String) listview.getItemAtPosition(pos);
             if(selectedFromList.equals("your_answer")) {
                   // to change the listview background
                   listview.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.your_color_id));

                   // to change the selected item background color
                   myView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.your_color_id));
             }
```

Comment: Thanks,Into my case when press the `listview item` it display the next `question - answers(options)`, So I have apply above code but it work for the only last queston.

Comment: I didn't get you what you want to do. If you want to show the next question options when a question is selected then check for position that you want to query ( increment to query next question or decrement to query previous question).

Comment: when start the app then display the question(Textview) and four options(listview), when select listview item then go to next questions, it works perfect but I want to change the color of the selected listview item when user select the answer, If answer is true then Change the background color of the `listview item`is green, and wrong then set the background color red(same as KBC).

Comment: I have go with your above code but it working for the only last question. please check my updated code as per your answer, into that when i select answer, I can see the toast notification but does not change the background color.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.because of there's no delay between questions in my code,so only last question display the effect of change the background.after add the `Handler.postDelayed();` it's working perfect.