# Setting all elements in a custom adapter listview to Visible/Invisible

Tags: android, android-listview, visibility, custom-adapter

I am trying to make a Button change the visibility of a single ImageButton in all of my Listview Elements. The problem i'm having is finding the right element to access, because i don't have an easy way to access a specific element in the Custom Adapter (i think)

Relevant code parts:

```
 public View getView(final int position, final View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi=convertView;
    if(convertView==null)
    {
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row_view, null);
    }

/*
 other non important view stuff
*/
if(deleteButton != null){
        deleteButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        deleteButton.setTag(position);
        deleteButton.setOnClickListener(deleteListener);
    }

    return vi;
}

public void setVisibility()
{
    if(deleteButton.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE){
        deleteButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); //Here i  want to access all elements
        Log.i("setVisibility", "Changing to "+ deleteButton.getVisibility() + " element: " + deleteButton.getTag()); 
//Logcat output: Changing to 0 element: 2


    } else if(deleteButton.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
        deleteButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); 
        Log.i("setVisibility", "Changing to "+ deleteButton.getVisibility() + " element: " + deleteButton.getTag());
//Logcat output: Changing to 4 element: 2

    }
}
```

Stuff i use in the Main Activity:

```
CustomAdapter listAdapter;
ListView listViewLeft;
ListView listViewRight;

OnCreate:
listAdapter=new CustomAdapter(this, link, names, names2, buttonText,context, plistArray); 
listViewLeft.setAdapter(listAdapter);
listViewRight.setAdapter(listAdapter);
```

I call on the method simply using:

```
OnClickListener editListener = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {
        listAdapter.setVisibility();
       }
 }
```

If anyone has any ideas then i'd really appreciate it, Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a really simple fix. I forgot calling:

```
listAdapter.notifiDataSetChanged();
```

But every time you call that method, the getView method is called, so i just added this in the custom adapter getView

```
if(deleteButton != null){
        if(deleteButton.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE){
            deleteButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else if(deleteButton.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
            deleteButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); 
            }
        deleteButton.setTag(position);
        deleteButton.setOnClickListener(deleteListener);
    }
```

And set the default in XML to visible. 
I'm not sure if this is the most efficient way to do it, but it works like intended at least :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to store index of item with invisible button or visibility value in the adapter and use it (of just set visibility to every view/convertView) in `getView()`. It's related to view reuse from ListView side.
 Refer to [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12459507/change-the-background-of-select-click-listview-item-android/12470571#12470571) to get the idea on how to fix it and to [this Romain Guy Google I/O talk](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70) for more details of ListView