# color changing while clicking the list view

Tags: android, listview, colors

My android code can change the background color into green of the first visible listview items with onClick event but when I scrolled down the listview and try to click the list then the green color does not appear. How to solve this issue any help will be highly appreciated. I have attached my code snippets herewith.

```
   public void onItemClick( AdapterView<?> parent, View item,   
                                  int position, long id) {



     for(int i=0; i<parent.getChildCount(); i++)
           {
               Log.d("TAG", "Number of times printed");
                if(i == position)
                {
                          parent.getChildAt(position).setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                         // Log.d("TAG","Green at position :: " + position);

                }
                else
                {
                          parent.getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
                }
            }
}
```

Comment: is it the same as in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12459507/change-the-background-of-select-click-listview-item-android/12470571#12470571 ?

Comment: i didn't get your question fully, do you want when user click list show that one item was selected with green color

Comment: @mindFreezer yes whenever the user selects the listViews it should be green and other list should be gray and when user scrolls the listviews and click then the listview should be green but I am not able to get it. When I scrolled the listView and click it is still gray.

Answer (score 1):

Define colors in color.xml file in values folder

make xml file with the following code in drawable folder listViewBackground.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:state_focused="true" 
      android:state_pressed="false" 
      android:drawable="@color/grey" />

<item android:state_focused="true" 
      android:state_pressed="true"
      android:drawable="@color/green"

       />

<item android:state_focused="false" 
      android:state_pressed="true"
      android:drawable="@color/green" />

<item android:drawable="@color/grey" />
```

and set this file as background for the list item

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
                  parent.getChildAt(position).setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
```

try this

```
    parent.getChildAt(position).setBackgroundColor(R.color.orange);
```

You need to define your color in color.xml in values folder-- vales/color.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
 <color name="orange">#e68c10</color>
</resources>
```

and also look for your function try using

```
public void onListItemClick(ListView parent,View v,int position,long id){}
```